# Sort posts by custom field value

Tags: custom-field

I tried fixing this for 5 days and my head is burning now. I bought a theme from GorilaThemes  and the developer doesn't get back to me on the forum either, so Im pretty much by myself now. can you guys please help?

There is a page where it lists cars with with the below query

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => array('gtcd','user_listing'),
                'posts_per_page' => '999' 

                 ));
                    if ( $query->have_posts() ) while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); global $post,$field, $fields, $fields2, $fields3; $fields = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mod1', true); $fields3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mod3', true); $fields2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mod2', true);  $symbols = get_option('gorilla_symbols'); $options = get_option('gorilla_fields');include(TEMPLATEPATH."/functions/var/default-box-one.php");include(TEMPLATEPATH."/functions/var/default-box-two.php");include(TEMPLATEPATH."/functions/var/default-box-three.php");
```

And below is the way they 'echo' Year, Body Style and Price.

```
$fields['year'], $fields['bodystyle'], $fields['price']
```

Now Im trying to sort the posts by its 'Year' which is '$fields['year']'. How do I do it? I tried the methods below but none of them worked.

METHOD 1

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
             'post_type' => array('gtcd','user_listing'),
             'posts_per_page' => '999' ,
             'orderby' => 'meta_value',
             'order' => 'ASC',
             'meta_key' => 'year'
```

Comment: do you sure that the `custom field` key is `year`?

Comment: To answer this we'd have to know where "year" field is stored. That isn't obvious from the code.

Comment: Where is it usually stored? Can I find the name in the database or in one of the meta php files?

Comment: There isn't really a "usually". I'd store it as post meta, but you don't have to. It could be an option or something in a custom table. Or it could be extracted from one of the post date columns in the `$wpdb->posts` table. You will have to dig through the theme code or browse the  database (your particular database) to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick. I had to use '_year"

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query(array(
       'post_type' => array('gtcd','user_listing'),
       'posts_per_page' => '999',
       'meta_key' => '_year',
       'orderby' => 'meta_value',               
       'order' => 'ASC' 
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line of code and your explanation, indicates that *year* may be stored as an index in a serialized array inside the `mod1` custom field.

```
$fields = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mod1', true );
```

If this is correct, the `WP_Query` object cannot (easily) be used to sort the posts by that value.

You could:

1. Run a custom query that can peek inside a PHP serialized array,
2. Place all post objects in an array and then sort them in PHP or
3. Add a custom field to each post (named *year*, for example) that can be used to sort the posts with the `WP_query` object.

How  you decide to do it depends on how many posts there are and how often you need to do this sort.

Without knowing more, the last option seems like the best if there are a large post count or if this sort is done on every page load, but it may require figuring what code runs when the *year* value is updated.